# What's an expression in C# and how can you recognize them?

Tags: c#, expression

I have trouble understanding what an expression in C# is and how you can conclude from a code fragment whether or not it's an expression.

Why are, for example, (((3))), new Button(), (int)3.5 and 3E-5 expressions?

Comment: "An expression is a sequence of one or more operands and zero or more operators that can be evaluated to a single value, object, method, or namespace."

Comment: Keeping it simple and less formal: anything that produces a value that you can assign to a variable.

Comment: "An expression in a programming language is a combination of one or more constants, variables, operators, and functions that the programming language interprets (according to its particular rules of precedence and of association) and computes to produce ("to return", in a stateful environment) another value. This process, as for mathematical expressions, is called evaluation. " https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expression_(computer_science)

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you, that's a pretty concise description. So 55, Brushes.Black, x == 2 are all expressions? Is x = 5*2; an expression? I'd guess not, since you can't assign x=5*2 to a variable.

Comment: Well, at the risk of being less concise, in the curly brace languages an assignment is an expression as well.  A bit quirky and not used that often, but does support syntax like a = b = c = 42; to initialize three variables to the same value.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the documentation about [expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expressions) in the [C# programming guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/):

> An expression is a sequence of one or more operands and zero or more operators that can be evaluated to a single value, object, method, or namespace. Expressions can consist of a literal value, a method invocation, an operator and its operands, or a simple name. Simple names can be the name of a variable, type member, method parameter, namespace or type.